# Add a blank record in SQL SELECT results

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT clientName FROM Clients;
```

resulting in:

```
clientName  
"Einstein"  
"Edison"  
"Newton"
```

I want to add an empty record on top of "Einstein" like this

```
clientName  
""
"Einstein"  
"Edison"  
"Newton"
```

Please help me with a SQL sintax for this, and i want it to work in msaccess.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `UNION`

```
SELECT DISTINCT '' AS clientName FROM Clients
UNION
SELECT clientName FROM Clients
```

Comment: it's not working. "Query input must contain at least one table or query" error.

Answer (score 1):

Try This Query:

```
SELECT '""' AS clientName FROM Clients UNION SELECT clientName FROM Clients
```

Actually this is more or like same as that of **J W**. But he seems to forget the **""**

Comment: it's not working. "Query input must contain at least one table or query" error.

Comment: Please check the Updated Query

Answer (score 0):

This is **`DB2`** version

```
SELECT '""' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION
SELECT SELECT clientName FROM Clients;
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick in Access is to change the query type to a Pass-Through query and then write it as Luv did with a few minor changes.  This is what it looks like against a WCS DB2 table.

```
SELECT '' AS DisplayName FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION
SELECT DB2ADMIN.ACACTDESC.DISPLAYNAME
FROM DB2ADMIN.ACACTDESC;
```